# Arduino Multiple SPI devices including CC3000 and MFRC522

Tags: arduino

I'm asking if how can I implement this one. I'm aware about multiple devices being connected over SPI, like having to select individual SS pin for each. Adafruit's CC3000 works fine alone along with the default Adafruit library. CC3000 uses SPI. MFRC522 RFID module by sonmicro (bought at Sparksfun) uses SPI too. It works fine too, independently. But whenever I connect them together, only WiFi works perfectly. I dont want to turn on and off the wifi to make way for the RFID to communicate since it takes some time for it to be connected in a wireless network. I want the two to work synchronously (or having to be scheduled but really fast that's unnoticeable by the user)

here's my code as of now. i cannot post it here as strange things happen i don't know why haha
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0bZsYo0xMH8YV9uWXJaRFdPT3M/view?usp=sharing

I'm thinking of replacing the RFID with SonMicro's SM130 RFID Module w/ SparkFun Eval board  with UART (convertible to I2c) or Adafruit's PN532 with I2c by default. Are these okay to be paired with SPIs like the CC3000? Or should I change CC3000 with the Official WiFi module (UART) or WiFly Module (SPI-to-UART)

Comment: Do both devices have chip selects?

Comment: yes. and I have set different for each, like pin 9 for RFID and 10 for the WiFi. I have change them alternatively but it didn't work. I don;t think that's the issue if 10 is by the default the SS pin since both libraries do support changing of the SS pins or the CS pin

Comment: Just because you've changed them in the software doesn't mean you've changed them in the hardware.

Comment: oh i see. so how can i do this? will i use jumper wires? or alter the libraries?

Comment: You would need to alter one or both of the shields.